# Babylon malware

Tags: firefox, bloatware, babylon

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Computer is infected by a virus or a malware, what do I do now?](https://superuser.com/questions/100360/computer-is-infected-by-a-virus-or-a-malware-what-do-i-do-now)

I hope someone can help. Babylon Search BS malware got installed on my firefox browser. I have followed every piece of deletion advice I can find but the Babylon Search page still comes up every time I open a new tab. How can I get rid of this crapware?

Comment: You need to tell us exactly what you have tried.  My first instinct is to tell you to reinstall Windows.

Comment: @Ramhound, a little extreme no?

Comment: @soandos That's about the only way to be safe there's no malware traces left.

Comment: @slhck, perhaps, but in the vast majority of cases, it is a known virus, with a known solution, and there will be nothing left. It is at least worth trying...

Answer (score 3):

I'd start with the steps explained on [support.babylon.com](http://support.babylon.com):

1. `Open Start -> Control Panel` and uninstall the program *Babylon* in `Add/Remove Programs`, `Uninstall a Program` or `Programs and Features`.
2. In Firefox, press <kbd>Alt</kbd>, <kbd>T</kbd>, <kbd>O</kbd> and change your homepage in the `General` tab.
3. In Firefox, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> and remove *Babylon* in the `Extensions` tab.

Sources:

- [Uninstall Babylon Software](http://support.babylon.com/index.php?/Knowledgebase/Article/View/177/0/uninstall-babylon-software)
- [Change Babylon Home Page](http://support.babylon.com/index.php?/Knowledgebase/Article/View/175/0/change-babylon-home-page)
- [Remove Toolbar and "Search the web (Babylon)"](http://support.babylon.com/index.php?/Knowledgebase/Article/View/213/0/uninstall-babylon-toolbar-software)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the answers provided in the post "[Computer is infected by a virus or a malware, what do I do now?](https://superuser.com/questions/100360/computer-is-infected-by-a-virus-or-a-malware-what-do-i-do-now)" ?
You should get rid of Babylon search this way.

If you can't the quickest way to clean is to reinstall the OS, the drivers, updates and all the applications you use and then do an image of your disk using [DriveImage XML](http://www.runtime.org/driveimage-xml.htm) and store it on DVDs or better, one of your drives (not the Windows one).

That way you'll have a good starting point and only the new updates to apply.